# ReferenceError: variable_name is not defined in EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, ejs

I'm trying to render a simple file passing a variable:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        <title>EXPORT <%= exportName%></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <p><%= exportName%></p>
        </header>

        <main>

        </main>

        <footer>

        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', async (req, resp) => {
  const pdfTemplate = ejs.render(
    path.join(__dirname, 'report_pdf.ejs'),
    { exportName: 'aaa' },
  );

  return resp.render(pdfTemplate);
});
```

But I keep getting:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Projects/Backend/my-service/dist/report_pdf.ejs:5
    3|     <head>
    4|         <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
 >> 5|         <title>EXPORT <%= exportName%></title>
    6|     <script defer src="index.js"></script></head>
    7| 
    8|     <body>

exportName is not defined
```

I'm using webpack to build up everything:

```js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const NodemonPlugin = require('nodemon-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'source-map' : false,
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
      '@Root': path.resolve(__dirname),
      '@Src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      '@Db': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/db/'),
      '@Models': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/models/'),
      '@Routes': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
      '@Security': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/security/'),
      '@Utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils/'),
      '@Static': path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/'),
      '@Img': path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/images/'),
    },
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  plugins: [
    new NodemonPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'static', to: 'static' },
      ],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '!!raw-loader!./src/views/pages/report_pdf.ejs',
      filename: 'report_pdf.ejs',
      chunks: ['main', 'owl_carousel'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

I can't find any solution on Stack Overflow. Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? This seems a bit complex - you're setting the view engine and using res.render but _also_ rendering the template manually - which time is the error? The webpack bundling is generally more relevant to client-side code, do you actually want to treat the template as HTML?